# MySQL Performance Issue with 32 GB RAM and Intel Xeon 2.70 GHz Quad Core processor

Tags: performance, optimization

I have an issue on running MySql on Windows server 2008 which has 32 GB Ram and Intel Xeon 2.70 Quad Core processor.

The database is only of 258 MB.
While running a php script which export the data from database and dumps into dbf files. It takes 50 mins.

CPU Usage goes around ~50%. mostly take by mysqld.exe. 
CPU Usage goes around ~30% even if a single user logs in. I tested with 3 users and it went upto 63%

Below is my current configuration for my.ini:

```
    [client] 
    port            = 3306 
    socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
    [mysqld]
    port= 3306
    socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
    basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
    tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
    datadir = "D:/ADAT_System/Database/data"
    pid_file = "mysql.pid"
    key_buffer = 16M
    max_allowed_packet = 1M
    sort_buffer_size = 512K
    net_buffer_length = 8K
    read_buffer_size = 256K
    read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
    myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
    log_error = "mysql_error.log"
    log-output=FILE
    slow_query_log = ON
    long_query_time = 5
    query_cache_size = 128MB
    query_cache_type = ON
    query_cache_limit = 10MB
    plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 
    skip-federated
    server-id
    innodb_data_home_dir = "D:/ADAT_System/Database/data"
    innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
    innodb_log_group_home_dir = "D:/ADAT_System/Database/data"
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
    innodb_log_file_size = 5M
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
    innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
    [mysqldump]
    quick
    max_allowed_packet = 16M
    [mysql]
    no-auto-rehash
    [isamchk]
    key_buffer = 20M
    sort_buffer_size = 20M
    read_buffer = 2M
    write_buffer = 2M
    [myisamchk]
    [mysqlhotcopy]
    interactive-timeout
```

Could someone please help me in optimizing the MySQL.I am pretty new to this.

Thanks,
Himanshu

Comment: Look at MySQLTuner-0.6. It is on codeplex. It gave me a huge amount of hints in optimizing our environment.  It will be a good starting point.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak In response to your comment, I had no intention of critiquing or requesting clarification from the author.  The request is very broad and specifically asked for help in optimizing the MySQL infrastructure.  My answer may very well resolve his issue.  If not, one can at least eliminate that before looking at the PHP or transport part of that issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I checked MySQL Tuner and it gave me a lot of suggestions, I am working on it right now. I don't see any comment from Jan Dvorak

Comment: His comment was on my answer.  I have undeleted my answer in case you want to up-mark it  or accept it - if it answered your question and was useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally a SQL request (Given that the DB is local) should be quicker than that. *granted.
Try looking here for a great list of performance Tweaking.
http://www.askapache.com/mysql/performance-tuning-mysql.html

That aside, I am presuming its the structure of your requests.
Try keep your call into very few requests (1-10) and handle the data as a lump sum.
Doing Many requests can hinder the system and drastically reduce that performance.
Your server has more than enough ram and processing power.

Thats the best i can offer for now.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion, we are working on some caching part of php script.

Answer (score 0):

Look at MySQLTuner-0.6.  It is on codeplex.  It gave me a huge amount of hints in optimizing our environment.